# Spring Boot OAuth2 - access to secured resource without authentication from specified address

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a question. I want to create simple microservice application using Spring Boot. I have two microservices: **auth-serivce** with port **8001**, which authenticate user and return token and **db-service** with port **8002**, which retrieves data from database. In **db-service** I have a simple rest controller and in this controller I have a method, witch finds the user by username, but by default this method is secured and I want to access to this resource from **auth-service** without authentication. How to do that?

Here is an example

**DbServiceController.java**

```
@RestController
public class DbServiceController {

    /**
     * This method is secured by default, so if I want to
     * access to this resouce I need to have a token,
     * but I want to prevent authentication for auth-service,
     * because I want to retrieve token by user, which was provided by this microservice
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User findByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
        return new User("john", "doe", new String[] {"ROLE_USER"});
    }

}
```

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider API gateway pattern:

http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-api-gateway-zuul/

API gateway can route different requests to different microservices e.g. :

- the request to: http://yourhost.com**/users** can be routed to one microservice: http://**microservice1/users**
- the request to: http://yourhost.com**/data**  can be routed to another microservice: http://**another-microservice/data**

And you can also implement security on API gateway and make it the only service that is available for users. So in this case all your microservices can communicate in private network without security but users will be authenticated on API gateway. It is enough if you don't store sensitive data. In other case I would suggest to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq4RzFdm1Y0 that explains how to secure microservices properly.

Comment: Hm.. this is really good concept, but I don't know, how to implement it. I want to do this: if I type address http://localhost:8001/user/john (which is secured by default) I expect, that browser throws an exception "Full authentication is required to access this resource", but I want to have an access from **auth-service**, without authorization